# I am getting "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want this to be able to filter post by the CURRENT USER and delete it. Someone told me to use .WHERE instead of .FILTER but neither of them are working and I get an Attribute Error. How can I get this working?

By the way I am able to delete ALL user post with just `db.session.query(Post).delete()` but I want it so it only deletes posts for CURRENT_USER.ID (the user that is currently logged into my session)

I added my current models:

````
@login_required
def delete_all_post():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        db.session.query(Post).delete().filter(Post.user_id == current_user.id)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('All of your posts has been deleted!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))```

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', {self.date_posted}')"

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(16), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
````

Comment: Can you paste your entire error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete()` return True/ False which is 0 or 1 which is `int` so you cannot do filter over it

try:
`db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.user_id == current_user.id).delete()`

Comment: `Query.delete()` returns the number of rows that matched the given filter (as reported by the DB), not "True / False".